# how to remove Description label on drupal 9 forum page

Tags: drupal

I created a forum in Drupal 9, and after adding the description I have a Label "Description" above it

this is the html code and how it looks on the /forum page

```
<div class="text-content clearfix field field--name-description field--type-text-long field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Description</div>
```

the label cannot be removed from the view panel in fields.

https://imgur.com/a/hBZGSAD